# Question based on boats and streams

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sonal and Deepali started swimming towards each other simultaneously from points A and B respectively situated at two ends of a 96 km long stretch of a river. Destinations of Deepali and Sonal were points A and B respectively. Both of them could swim at 12 kmph in still water. When they started, it was high tide and Sonal swam against the stream. As soon as they met, the tide changed to ‘low tide’ and then Deepali faced the resistance of the stream. Deepali and Sonal took 7 hr 12 min and 8 hr min to reach their destinations respectively. [Speed of the stream during high and low tide need not necessarily be the same.] "
Find the speed of the stream during low tide.

Sonal upstream speed = 12-v where v is speed of the river
Deepali downstream speed= (12+v) km/hr
Their relative speed= 24 km/hr
Hence they will meet after 4 hrs
Now what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Call the meeting point M.  Then AM=4(12-v) and MB=4(12+v).

Answer (score 1):

Let $v = $ current at high tide.

Say they met at time $t$.  So Deepali swam $(12 + v)t$ and Sonal swam $(12 -v)t$.  (Deepali is swimming with the current, Sonal against).

And $(12+v)t + (12-v)t = 96$

Tide changed.  Let $w = $ current at low tide (in opposite direction).

Deepali swam for another $7 \frac {12}{60} - t$ time thus swam another $(7\frac {12}{60} - t)(12 -w)$.  (Deepali is now swimming against the current.)

$(12+v)t + (7\frac {12}{60} - t)(12 -w) = 96$

Sonal swam for another $8 - t$ (did you forget to type the minutes?) and thus swam another $(8 - t)(12+w)$.  (Sonal is now swimming with the current.)

$(12-v)t + (8-t)(12+w) = 96$

We have three equations and three unknowns.  Should be solvable.